# How to specify two JREs in a single installer for different launchers?

Tags: install4j

I have an install4j (v4.x) project that has 2 different launchers (for 2 different tasks) created on application install. Is there any way to specify a separate (2nd) JRE for the 2nd launcher (not the one specified in the final media file)?

***A bit an offtopic but...***

Why would i need that? Actually i need a full copy of the JRE from the media file for the 2nd launcher (which is an updater-type application) so that it could update main application's JRE. If updater would works on the same JRE as the application it wouldn't be able to do so.

Maybe there is a better way to update application's JRE with the one i need?

P.S. I know about new update features of install4j 5.x, but we re not using it for several reasons, so its out of question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

- On General Settings->Java version you add an environment variable `MY_UPDATER_JAVA_HOME`
  to the search sequence and move it to the the top of the list.
- In the installer, use a "Copy files and directories" action to duplicate the JRE to some other directory
- On Installer->Screens & Actions, add an empty custom installer application, set its "Default execution mode" property to "Unattended mode"
- Add a "Run executable or batch file" action to the "Startup" node of the new installer application. With that action, you call your updater launcher. In the "Specific environment variables" property, you set `MY_UPDATER_JAVA_HOME` to the location of the copied JRE.

You would then call the installer application and not your updater directly and it would run with the duplicated JRE.

If you do not want to keep two JREs around in the installation directory, you could change the "Default execution mode" property to "Unattended mode with progress dialog" and add a "Copy files and directories" action to copy the JRE to a specific directory in the temp directory if it does not already exist.

Comment: Thats a pretty good workaround! And seems that there is no simple way  to do the same with just install4j settings/tools. So i'd say this answer is enough for me.